# CalDav web client or libraries that works with Google Calendars WebDav server / api

Tags: google-calendar-api, caldav

Does anyone know if there are any CalDav web clients or even any client libraries that will connect to the Google Calendar CALDAV API/server (we the recent oAuth2 additions)? We want to do this so that Google calendars can be managed in a standard way, and embedded in our own application.

Answer (score 1):

One possible library is [gaye/dav](https://github.com/gaye/dav) on github. It was initially written for Firefox OS and provides support for an OAuth2 transport.

That aside, adding OAuth2 support to any other existing library is probably not that hard. When you know it is a Google CalDAV server, do the OAuth exchange to get the access token. Then, if the library has a hook (or a function that can be monkeypatched) that runs just before a request is sent, set the request header `Authorization: Bearer <oauth access token>` with each request.